# Как присоединить к решению проект из GitHub?

Tags: visual-studio, git, github, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013

Скажите, можно ли, и если можно, то как встроить в свое решение выборочный проект из гитхаба? Ну например, если мне нужно подключить библиотеку (с исходником) и я не хочу клонировать все решение из гита.